# need to get the command information over ssh and the input from file

Tags: shell-script, ssh, io-redirection

I am writing a script to get the command information of the remote machine usinf while and for loop. PFB the script. But the script ends by giving the single command information only. I have multiple commands in this file `(CMDS=$HOMEDIR/cmnd.txt)`. If I don't use ssh all the commands working fine, but when I use ssh it executes first command only.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOMEDIR=/home/448130
CMDS=$HOMEDIR/cmnd.txt
while read -r line
do
  for i in $(cat hostname.txt);
  do
    echo "*****************************  $line output begins  ********************************";
    #echo $line
    ssh $i $line
    echo "*****************************  $line output ends  ********************************";
  done
done < $CMDS
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Could you please clarify a little more what you actually want to achieve?

You may find several methods for running local commands remotely at http://backreference.org/2011/08/10/running-local-script-remotely-with-arguments/

And a pretty similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376166/execute-a-command-on-remote-hosts-via-ssh-from-inside-a-bash-script

Comment: I am trying to fetch some details like uptime, uname, etc from a remote machine over ssh. For this I am calling the commands from a txt file.

Comment: When i execute the script without ssh locally it gives the output how i am expecting. But when i executes wth ssh command it executes the first command of the input file only.

Comment: *****************************  uptime output begins  ******************************
 14:37:25 up 3 days, 13 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.18, 0.14
*****************************  uptime output ends  ********************************
*****************************  uname output begins  ******************************
Linux
*****************************  uname output ends  ********************************
This kind of output i am expecting

Comment: I am able to get the output perfectly, when executing the script locally. but when is use "ssh $i $line" it executes first command from the file only and then the loop ends

Comment: Your earlier link helped me to fix this.

Comment: You might also consider using something like https://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en or https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/dsh/ or https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/ so you don't have to emulate this via a script ...
Or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243750/how-can-i-automate-running-commands-remotely-over-ssh for some more alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ssh`, the standard input is passed to the remote command. The remote command doesn't actually do anything with it, but the local `ssh` process has no way to know. To avoid this, since you don't want to pass any input to the remote command, redirect the input of `ssh` to `/dev/null`.

Don't forget to [double quote variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  for i in $(cat hostname.txt);
  do
    echo "*****************************  $line output begins  ********************************";
    #echo $line
    ssh "$i" "$line" </dev/null
    echo "*****************************  $line output ends  ********************************";
  done
done < "$CMDS"
```